# Simulacrum: macro implementation not found

Tags: scala, typeclass, simulacrum

I've got a simple code in Scala to try simulacrum lib:

```
import simulacrum._
@typeclass trait Semigroup[A] {
  @op("|+|") def append(x: A, y: A): A
}
```

But this doesn't work. Compiler says

> Error:(3, 2) macro implementation not found: macroTransform (the most
>   common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in
>   the same compilation run that defines them) @typeclass trait
>   Semigroup[A] {

What can cause this error?
I do not create a macro, I just reuse an existing one.

My build.sbt file is simple:

```
name := "Macr"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
libraryDependencies += "com.github.mpilquist" %% "simulacrum" % "0.12.0"
```

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.5

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. Thanks! Changing Scala back to 2.12.4 or JDK to 1.8 works

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Oleg Pyzhcov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758343/oleg-pyzhcov) in the comments, [macros don't work with Scala 2.12.4 and 2.12.5 when compiling on Java 9 or 10](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.5). However, [this has been fixed in Scala 2.12.6](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.6), so upgrading should solve the problem.